# Polymer 2.0 Animation in DOM-IF

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

How should I do animation in CSS in start and end displaying element in `dom-if`?

i see some examples of how to do this i `dom-repeat` but I have no idea how to code this in `dom-if`.

I don't know how to detect is element appers on screen or not. I know i can make observable on dom-if variable, but what next? The elemet is still null after switch new value in dom-if, just after second the element isn't null. How to detect this, and add animation?

If this will by simpler - I can have only "start" animation

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.